# Signature of whenComplete from CompletableFuture

Tags: java, scala, completable-future

Does anyone know to translate the `whenComplete` method of java `CompletableFuture` to Scala? I really don't know how to do it and I'm kinda' stuck. Thank you

Comment: You mean you want the same semantics but using Scala futures? In that case isn't `onComplete` enough?

Comment: No, I mean I'm using java CompletableFuture inside a scala class and I need the whenComplete signature translated. I cant get it work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example that shows you how it might work (inside the scala REPL)...

```scala
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_181).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
```

Create a future that waits for 5 seconds, then completes returning a string value. (See also the note below explaining how this works.)

```scala
scala> val future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {() =>
     |   Thread.sleep(5000) // Wait 5,000 ms (5 seconds).
     |   "We done did it!"
     | }
future: java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture[String] = java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@5a466dd[Not completed]
```

Now have some code execute when the future has finished. (This is where you should begin with your own `whenComplete` implementation.)

```scala
scala> future.whenComplete {(result, error) =>
     |   println(s"Result was: '$result', error was: '$error'")
     | }
Result was 'We done did it!'; error was 'null'
res0: java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture[String] = java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@3ea9a091[Completed normally]
```

(Note that, in this case, the future completed before I was able to type in the `whenComplete` method. This is clearly a race condition, so if you paste the whole lot into the REPL at once, you may see that `res0` is determined to have "Not completed", and then see the output of the `whenComplete` function.)

So what's going on here, because this code doesn't look much like the *JavaDoc* for the associated classes?

It's a little *Scala magic* called *[single abstract methods](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#lambda-syntax-for-sam-types)*. Essentially, if an asbtract class (or trait) has a single abstract method, then you can replace an instance of that class with the definition of the abstract method. Further, *Scala* knows which class is relevant from the argument list of the associated function.

Let's start with `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync`, which takes a single `Supplier[T]` argument. In *Scala* terms, this type looks like this:

```scala
trait Supplier[T] {
  def get(): T
}
```

So we could have written the creation of the `future` element as follows instead:

```scala
scala> import java.util.function.Supplier
import java.util.function.Supplier

scala> val future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {
     |   new Supplier[String] {
     |     override def get(): String = {
     |       Thread.sleep(5000) // Wait 5,000 ms (5 seconds).
     |       "We done did it!"
     |     }
     |   }
     | }
future: java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture[String] = java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@35becbd4[Not completed]
```

Because the *Scala* compiler knows that `supplyAsync` takes a `Supplier[T]`, and because `Supplier[T]` has a *single abstract method*, `get`, the compiler is able to accept the abbreviated form that uses a *function literal* as the definition of both `Supplier` and its `get` method.

We then use the same approach with the `whenComplete` method. Here, the type of argument is a `BiConsumer[T, U]` (where `T` is the type of value returned by the future, and `U` is an exception type), which takes a *single abstract method* `accept`. (This type also has an `andThen` method, but that's not abstract, so it doesn't matter to *Scala*.) So, to have been more explicit, we could have written the following:

```scala
scala> import java.util.function.BiConsumer

scala> future.whenComplete {
     |   new BiConsumer[String, Throwable] {
     |     override def accept(result: String, error: Throwable): Unit = {
     |       println(s"Result was: '$result', error was: '$error'")
     |     }
     |   }
     | }
Result was 'We done did it!'; error was 'null'
res0: java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture[String] = java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@3ea9a091[Completed normally]
```

Both approaches are valid, so feel free to use whichever one makes sense to you...

Note that `whenComplete` is a *lot* uglier than conventional *Scala* code typically requires: If the future threw an exception instead of successfully finishing, then `error` will be non-`null`; otherwise, `result` will contain the result of the future, which could also be `null`.

If at all possible, I would strongly recommend using *Scala* `Future`s instead. Far more functional, and far more elegant than those in *Java*.

You can convert a *Java* `CompletableFuture` into a *Scala* `Future` with the following implicit conversion:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.language.implicitConversion
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

implicit def completableFutureToFuture[T](cf: CompletableFuture[T]): Future[T] = {
  val p = Promise[T]() // Promise monitoring result of java cf.

  // Handle completion of Java future.
  cf.whenComplete {(result, error) =>

    // If error is not null, then future failed.
    if(error ne null) p.failure(error)

    // Otherwise, it succeeded with result.
    else p.success(result)
  }

  // Return the Scala future associated with the promise.
  p.future
}
```

You can then handle completion of the *Java* future far more elegantly (again, in the REPL, with the above defined):

```scala
scala> val scalaFuture = future // Implicit conversion called.
scalaFuture: scala.concurrent.Future[String] = Future(Success(We done did it!))

scala> scalaF.onComplete {
     |   case Success(s) => println(s"Succeeded with '$s'")
     |   case Failure(e) => println(s"Failed with '$e'...")
     | }
```